# replace x,y points with diffrent value in matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, opencv, coordinates

I detected with OpenCV some circles with specific pattern.
[image]

I made array from it with x,y coordinates and a value from this point.

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

  if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img,(i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

        temperatureArrayValue = np.uint16(np.mean(rawData[(i[1]-5):(i[1]+5),(i[0]-5):(i[0]+5)]))

        temperatureArray[temperatureArrayIteration][0] = i[0] #640
        temperatureArray[temperatureArrayIteration][1] = i[1] #480
        temperatureArray[temperatureArrayIteration][2] = temperatureArrayValue
```

My main goal is to is to detect every circle in this pattern, if not put coordinates where circle should be and put there a value = 0. This helps me to compare few frames to find out how the value inside circles changes in time.

This code above don't detect that 1 circle is actually the highest circle in the picture. I don't know how to compare two arrays and be sure that every element of array corresponds to specific circle. Frames is from video so coordinates change dynamically

Comment: Please refactor your question as it is very difficult to understand.  1. `My main goal is to is to detect every circle in this pattern` - you are already detecting all the circle in the  image. 2. `This code above don't detect that 1 circle is actually the highest circle in the picture` - didn't get this

Comment: If you read to the end you will understand that I detect it from video stream. This is just a sample frame how it looks like in best case, but my algorithm don't detect every circle in whole stream especially when camera operator move it more than I expect